# Axis2 giving NonRepeatableRequestException: Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity

Tags: soap, wsdl, apache-axis, wsdl2java

With a single generated SOAP class I am getting a NonRepeatableRequestException and have no idea how to solve it.

I have one single class generated by wsdl2java
`.\axis2-1.8.2\bin\wsdl2java.bat  --output output.axis --test-case --package com.mycompany.axis --sync -uri zws_monthly_invoice.wsdl`

I consume the service like this to authenticate the user (otherwise I receive 401 Error: Unauthorized)

```
    ZWS_MONTHLY_INVOICEStub stub = new ZWS_MONTHLY_INVOICEStub();

    Options options = stub._getServiceClient().getOptions();
    HttpTransportPropertiesImpl.Authenticator auth = new HttpTransportPropertiesImpl.Authenticator();
    auth.setPreemptiveAuthentication(true);
    auth.setPassword("myPassword");
    auth.setUsername("myUser");
    options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE,auth);

    ZWS_MONTHLY_INVOICEStub.Z_OMA_FAKT_AUFTRAG_CREATE payload = new ZWS_MONTHLY_INVOICEStub.Z_OMA_FAKT_AUFTRAG_CREATE();

    ZWS_MONTHLY_INVOICEStub.ZAUF_FAKT_POS_IF_OMEGA_T items = new ZWS_MONTHLY_INVOICEStub.ZAUF_FAKT_POS_IF_OMEGA_T();
    payload.setIT_INVOICE_ITEMS(items);

    ZWS_MONTHLY_INVOICEStub.Z_OMA_FAKT_AUFTRAG_CREATEResponse x = stub.z_OMA_FAKT_AUFTRAG_CREATE(payload);

    System.out.println("Z_OMA_FAKT_AUFTRAG_CREATEResponse=" + x.toString());
```

when I run it, I get following exceptions:

```
 [main] INFO org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender -- Unable to send to url[http://mycompany.com:8050/sap/..../500/.../zws_monthly_invoice]
org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: null
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:187)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.impl.httpclient4.RequestImpl.execute(RequestImpl.java:210)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:194)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(AbstractHTTPTransportSender.java:386)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPTransportSender.invoke(AbstractHTTPTransportSender.java:214)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:431)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:399)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:150)
    at com.mycompany.axis.ZWS_MONTHLY_INVOICEStub.z_OMA_FAKT_AUFTRAG_CREATE(ZWS_MONTHLY_INVOICEStub.java:181)
    at com.mycompany.axis.SoapAxisStaticMainTest.testz_OMA_FAKT_AUFTRAG_CREATE(SoapAxisStaticMainTest.java:82)
    at com.mycompany.axis.SoapAxisStaticMainTest.main(SoapAxisStaticMainTest.java:38)
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.NonRepeatableRequestException: Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity.
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:225)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:431)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:266)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(AbstractHTTPTransportSender.java:386)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPTransportSender.invoke(AbstractHTTPTransportSender.java:214)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:431)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:399)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:150)
    at com.mycompany.axis.ZWS_MONTHLY_INVOICEStub.z_OMA_FAKT_AUFTRAG_CREATE(ZWS_MONTHLY_INVOICEStub.java:181)
    at com.mycompany.axis.SoapAxisStaticMainTest.testz_OMA_FAKT_AUFTRAG_CREATE(SoapAxisStaticMainTest.java:82)
    at com.mycompany.axis.SoapAxisStaticMainTest.main(SoapAxisStaticMainTest.java:38)
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:187)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.impl.httpclient4.RequestImpl.execute(RequestImpl.java:210)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:194)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.NonRepeatableRequestException: Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity.
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:225)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    ... 13 more
```

Some write it is the broken authentication, but I thing problem ist somewhat different.

Guys in [NonRepeatableRequestException after adding Basic Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52035119/nonrepeatablerequestexception-after-adding-basic-auth) write, with one liner, but where do I put that line?
`post.setEntity(new BufferedHttpEntity(new InputStreamEntity(input)));`

Thanx for your help

Answer (score 0):

I could solve my problem by replacing the Authentication with Authorisation with the following code:

```
 String credentials = sapSoapUsername + ":" + sapSoapPassword;
 String encodedCredentials = Base64.getEncoder()
     .encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
 String authorizationHeader = "Basic " + encodedCredentials;
 Options options = stub._getServiceClient().getOptions();
 Map<String, String> property = new HashMap<>();
 property.put("Authorization", authorizationHeader);
 options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.HTTP_HEADERS, property);
```